# c++ multicast feed

Tags: c++, multicast

I am trying to create applications which receives multicast data feed.

If I have multiple applications which receives the data feed from the same multicast data interface, does it actually increase the overall network load?

My thinking is that if those 3 applications listen to the same multicast feed, the data shall be somehow sent to those application at once, so they shall not increase the overall network load.

Can anyone offer some advice on how the multicast feed actually work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple consuming applications of the same multicast data on a single piece of hardware the data has to be copied from the kernel mode into the user space for each consuming application.

- You will not see additional bandwidth if you measure the data at the NIC.
- You will see additional CPU load spent in the kernel as the network stack copies the multicast messages to userspace for each consuming application.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I heard something about OpenOnLoad and kernel bypassing. Would this somehow solve the increasing CPU load problem?

Comment: OpenOnLoad (from SolarFlare) can be of help.  I don't know of any other types of kernel bypassing that can be used.

Comment: Each network card manufacturer has their own kernel bypass or I/O acceleration technology (in fact Intel has something literally called I/OAT).  Knowing whether this will "solve" your hypothetical CPU load problem is quite another matter.